# Truck won't start with key, but will remote start

Tags: chevrolet, starting, wiring, suburban

1996 chevy suburban 1500 4/4 5.7 liter vortec ... My truck won't start when I turn the key. I get nothing like its not getting juice. But when I use a test light it has juice on the starter. So when I take my test light to the crank fuse and then turn it over it starts and runs fine. When I turn it off, it does the same thing ... Any ideas what could be going on? ... confused.

Comment: I have edited your question to hopefully make it more clear. If this does not adequately describe what is going on, please edit it yourself and make it more clear.

Comment: When you turn the key on, does the dash light up? Do you have access to the accessories?

Answer (score 2):

There's two power wires going to the starter. The big one is always on, and the little one is controlled by the key switch/remote start system. So, measure power at the little wire; my guess is that you don't get any power there while the key's in the start position.

I think the next thing I would do is find the point in the wiring where the remote start system is connected to the start signal wire. This might take some legwork. I would venture an early guess that it's related to the installation of the remote start system.

If you don't see anything obvious, just keep checking for power from the key switch on the start signal circuit along its length until you find the break.